# What is the gist of this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> Persons do not become a society by living in physical proximity, any more than a man ceases to be socially influenced by being so many feet or miles removed from others. ..........  {Individuals do not even compose a social group because they all work for a common end.}"

<sup>Source: [Democracy and Education by John Dewey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_and_Education)</sup>

I don't understand the sentence in the bracket.   Does it mean that those who work for a common end (a common goal) cannot be called a social group nor establish a social group?

Can anyone help me understand the gist of the sentence?
What is the point it tries to convey?

Comment: It doesn't mean that they *cannot* be called a social group.  What it means is that merely working for a common end is not *sufficient* to call people a social group; it takes more than just that.

Answer (score 2):

This is what that line seems to be saying:

> Just because people work towards a common goal does not necessarily mean that they constitute (or are) a social group.

Your understanding is correct.